# use of conduit for ducts

Tags: ducts

I need 2" ducts in this room I'm building.  Flexible ducts and conduit are about the same price.  I have high heat requirements.  Can I use conduit for ductwork?  What are the pros / cons?

Thanks

Comment: There are a lot of different types of metal & plastic conduit with different capabilities. Is there a specific type you were considering? How high is "high heat"?

Comment: The conduit is polyurethane rated for 200F.  The duct is aluminum.  High heat is >=100C.

Comment: I think you've just answered your own question. 100C = 212F > 200F. That won't work. Or rather, it *might* work but no guarantees and therefore **NOT RECOMMENDED**.

Comment: any implications or problems for using conduits for ducts generally?  also we're just safeguarding air here not live wires ;-)

Comment: Not that I know of. Logically, conduits for ducts should be fine whereas ducts for conduits is absolutely not (unless rated for such a purpose). But others may have more to add.

Comment: thx.  are there any implications to having small (.75") bottlenecks in the duct?

Comment: A lot will depend on how much air & how hot. Just like smaller-than-normal wire is not good for electricity, smaller-than-normal ductwork will constrict the flow of air which could cause problems.

Comment: thanks, feel free to chime in here:https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/152292/implications-of-small-bottleneck-in-ductwork